# How do I distribute my software?

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, deployment

I recently made a program with VB.Net for a client.

The program connects to an Oracle database.

I am using the ClickOnce deployment for Visual Studio, however, when I transfer the ClickOnce program to another computer, it still requires me to install Oracle first.

The Oracle database file needed to install is above 200mb.. I am looking for a way to minimize the size of the file and also simplify the process of installing the program.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What edition and version are you using?